# Where to buy E-ZPass at JFK?

Tags: jfk, tolls

I need to purchase an [EZPass](https://www.e-zpassny.com/en/about/plans.shtml) for my JFK rental car.  Is there a shop in the airport that sells these?  I understand rental companies sell it as a service, but I would like to have my own pass.

Comment: Hold on.  Are you sure you need to buy an EZ Pass?  Most rental agencies offer EZ Pass as an option.

Comment: Yes. I want to have my own EZ Pass

Comment: @Johns-305 He says "I understand rental companies sell it as a service, but I would like to have my own pass."  Might actually be cheaper, if he's going to be doing this a lot.

Comment: The rental agencies charge a hefty fee for using theirs (often a per-day fee that might apply on days you don't even use the thing as long as you've used it once). Getting your own could work out in your favor even with the deposit, depending on how much you plan to pay in tolls, but you'd have to do the math for your trip to find out.

Comment: @Andy Yes, I know.  OP edited the question after I posted my comment.

Comment: You should also ask if it's possible to move the transponder to different vehicles.  If not, your calculations change in their favor.

Comment: I got my ezpass when I lived in PA via the PTC, and I know I can add more than one car via their website.. and I don't even live in PA anymore.  Heh... actually the NY Ezpass customer site looks almost identical to the PA one, so its probably the exact same software just slightly rebranded for each state.

Comment: @Johns-305 I did find this; the answer seems to be yes:  https://www.e-zpassny.com/en/faq/rentalcars.shtml

Comment: Cool.  Is there a place in or very near JFK I can buy one?  I do not want to be one of 'those guys' that stops to pay cash

Comment: If you get it at the bridge / tunnel, you'll probably have to pay cash + whatever the cost of the transponder is, but after that you wouldn't be "that guy" anymore :-)

Comment: @gatorback what did you end up doing?

Comment: I ended up with an iPass

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there are lots of retails stores where you can get EZ Pass On-The-Go.  https://www.e-zpassny.com/en/onthego/locations.shtml.  If one of those retailers (7-11, etc.) are in the airport they may have them there.  Unfortunately I don't have any first-hand knowledge of being able to obtain one at the airport.

Otherwise, it appears that you can get them an MTA cash lanes at some bridges and tunnels as well.  So if you're going through / over one of those, skip EZpass at the rental agency, and ask for one in the cash lane.